# Clion Doesn't recognize my swift toolchain path

Tags: swift, swift3, ubuntu-16.04, clion

I'm trying to configure clion for a swift project, but it just doesn't recognize the swift toolchain path.

`$ which swift`

produces the output

`/usr/bin/swift/bin/swift`

so the toolchain is there but clion just doesn't recognize it

[image]

How do i make this work?

Answer (score 6):

You should use `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain`

There's `/usr/bin/swift` under the above directory and it makes CLion happy.

Answer (score 3):

I used the following successfully:

```
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/Swift_2.3.xctoolchain
```

I'm running OS X El Capitan, Version 10.11.6 with Xcode 8.2.1

Answer (score 3):

for anyone with the same problem, Cgarcia E88's comment [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000200464-I-can-t-set-swift-toolchain-path-in-ubuntu-CLION-)
might help.

> Apparently the path you choose must contain the folder `usr` underneath,  so in you case it should be just `/` but in general if swift is located at `SOME_PATH/usr/bin/swift` then you must select `SOME_PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows, try using
`C:\Library\Developer\Toolchains\unknown-Asserts-development.xctoolchain`

Answer (score -2):

CLion Swift plugin expects path to the whole toolchain, not the swift binary. In your case the correct patch probably would be "/usr/bin/swift"

Comment: I've fixed it, actually `clion` expects a directory structure of `swift/usr/bin/<swift-binary>` while mine was `swift/bin/<swift-binary>`

Comment: Unable to fix it. Suggestions?

Comment: @incorelabs Please provide more details. Which CLion & plugin versions are you using? What exactly are you entering into the field and what is the result?