# "Swift toolchain path is not configured" on Clion? (Windows version)

Tags: swift, clion

So I installed CLion so that I could use write swift code on Windows. After installing both Clion and Swift toolchain, I got the message "swift toolchain path not configured. The path Clion originally provided did not work and I have no clue what path I should point Clion to. Any clues?

I tried changing the path provided but to no avail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clion Doesn't recognize my swift toolchain path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43722764/clion-doesnt-recognize-my-swift-toolchain-path)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.